# Preventing text clutter on Weather app

Tags: layout, design

I am currently working on a Pollen application. The biggest issue I have is dealing with text clutter and information overload.

Here is my app so far:

http://puu.sh/9bjDd/3169bceb1d.jpg

[image]

The app is incomplete without the tips section under `pollen severity`, however, if there is too much text, users are not sure what to read.

How should I prevent the visual clutter while displaying enough information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few suggestions to remove unnecessary information on the screen:

1. You don't necessarily need to show the exact figures for tomorrow and day after tomorrow, just provide an indication of whether it is going to be higher or lower compared to today (so you can use a graph/chart).
2. Instead of showing the different levels of severity when you already have the percentage level, you should show a chart that shows how the percentage relates to the severity rating (e.g. very high = 80-100%).
3. You can use icons for pollen types instead of text description.
4. I suggest putting the date somewhere else because people only see the information for the current date on this screen anyway.

An extra tip to reduce visual clutter is to be careful about the images that you use, and perhaps even have an area where the background is going to be consistent so that there will not be so much variation in the text colour or lack of contrast when you have a image that has light and bright colours.